# The word "most" in sentences

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I made up a sentence:

"I love you most."

Does it mean that I love you more than I love others or I love you more than others do?

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. Until there is more information, its meaning remains unclear.

Comment: @RonaldSole I disagree; in a romantic conversation, couples may banter "I love you / I love you more / I love you most", so it make sense to me in that way.

Comment: @Danneyland True - but it also makes sense the other way. That's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It means you love them more than any other person that you know.

For example, if you have a favourite singer, you prefer them *the most* out of all the singers you know. This doesn't mean other fans can't consider them their favourite too, it only means that they are *your* favourite.

In English, we use *more* and *most* to indicate **how much** we do things like love, prefer, dance, and so on. We also use *better* and *best* to describe **how well** we do things like dance, paint, and sing. Let's compare:

- She dances *more* than him.
- She dances *the most* in her group.
- She dances *better* than him.
- She dances *the best* in her group.

Comment: Then how about "I scare you most"? Does it mean that I scare a lot of people but you are the weakest victim of all? According to your way of thinking, it does, but in my opinion it means that I am your worst nightmare (there are many things that scares you but I am the most scary). What do you think?